# Question about SSH and UFW

Tags: ssh, firewall, ufw, github

I am sorry if this is a dumb question. Basically, I wanted to enable a ssh connection to github. I am not that much familiar with ssh(and UFW) so I was wondering if I need to activate UFW to secure my laptop now that I am going to be using ssh. Or is it unnecessary to activate UFW if I am going to be just connecting to GitHub? I have been using ubuntu for 3 months now but haven’t enabled UFW as someone said it’s unnecessary(and also it looks too complicated). 
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UFW is a firewall. It can e.g. deny incoming connections to prevent remote machines from accessing any services that might run on your local computer and listen on any network ports (or it can also do a lot more fine-grained filtering in both directions, if you set it up).

Normally there's no reason why you should not have UFW running on your local machine with default settings (allow outgoing, deny incoming). As long as you are not running any server applications on your local machine that need to be accessible from outside, this is fine.

Connecting from your local machine to a remote server (e.g. GitHub) via ssh also works with UFW running as long as outgoing traffic is allowed.

I'd recommend to enable UFW and make sure it allows outgoing and denies incoming traffic on your local machine, to improve its security without interfering with your internet access:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw default deny incoming
```

If you ever need to specifically allow incoming traffic on a specific port (or for a specific known service) you can do that by running either of these (because e.g. ssh is known to use port 22):

```
sudo ufw allow in ssh
sudo ufw allow in 22
```

But again, you don't need that to connect to a remote server as a client.

Comment: Thnaks a lot for taking time to answer. I just have a question. If I deny incoming via ufw, will that prevent me from doing pull requests/cloning repo?

Comment: Nope. Denying incoming traffic will only deny requests originating from a remote source. It does not deny incoming responses to your own requests. When you do a git pull or visit a website, you send the request and the server responds.